# EmberJs : #each loop not detecting the array defined in the component

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, handlebars.js

This might seem simple, but i am missing something here. Please help me out.

in the component's JS file -

```
weekShorts: computed(function() {
  return new Array('S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S');
}),
```

and then in hbs file -

```
{{#each day in weekShorts}}
  <td>  {{day}}</td>
{{else}}
  <td>
    No items in days
  </td>
{{/each}}
```

The output is always "No items in days".

Although, just printing {{weekShorts}} anywhere else, displays

```
S,M,T,W,T,F,S
```

Why is the #each loop not executing the loop over the array at all?

**EDIT** - This works !!!, as suggested in the comments for 2.x

```
{{#each weekShorts as |day|}}
          <td>  {{day}}</td>
        {{else}}
          <td>
            No items in days
          </td>
        {{/each}}
```

Comment: What is your ember version? If it is 2.x, use 'each weekSorts as |day|'.

Comment: @ykaragol Thanks for the suggestion. I am using 2.4.3, and have made the change as you suggested, but it still behaves the same. Added an edit in the question, for reference.

Comment: Hey it's just a typo :) not weekShorts but weekSorts.

Comment: @ykaragol OMG.. sorry, yes.. your suggestion is correct. I was not aware that 2.x the pattern is that way. Great man. Thank you very much !!! i can accept an answer if you add one now .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ember version is greater than 1.12, use as:

```
{{#each weekShorts as |day|}}
```

To read further, look at [deprecations' blog](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_code-in-code-syntax-for-code-each-code)